# How to prevent Netbeans 6.9 from storing widget properties in a properties file

Tags: java, ide, netbeans

I'm learning to use Netbeans and for my intro pet projects, I don't want it storing widget properties in a properties file.  For example, by default, it puts the text property of a JLabel into a properties file.  There's a checkbox to disable it per property but is there a way to do that globally?  And is there a way to easily disable this for 20 widgets I've already defined?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  The reason that Netbeans is putting the text into properties files is to make it easier for you (or someone else) to internationalize your application.

Comment: Understood.  But these are just toy apps that I'm creating.  So I want to see everything in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it on a per-form level by going into Design mode, selecting the topmost item in the Inspector window, then unchecking the `Automatic Internationalization` property.

You can also disable it globally by going to `Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Gui Builder` and changing `Automatic Internationalization` to `off`.